# Split css styles up using php into an array

Tags: php, css, multidimensional-array

I have the following css code

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

i would like to split this up into an php array e.g.

```
array(
  h1 => array(
    color => #333
    font-size => 12px )
  h2 => array(
    color => #333
    font-size => 12px )
  h3 => array(
    color => #333
    font-size => 12px )
  h4 => array(
    color => #333
    font-size => 12px )
)
```

Does anyone know how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: No, he wants to parse it into a php _structure_ (namely an array)

Comment: -1. Don't like a php qw with no php-code.

Comment: [**What have you you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I currently have ($x is the whole css file i have loaded), this gets rid of the comments and only splits the css out into an array if the css file is in an inline format. 'foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $x) as $line) {
  if(substr($line, 0, 2) == '/*') {
} else {
  $array = explode('{', $line);
  $header = $array[0];
  $content = $array[1];
  $content = str_replace('{', '', $content);
  $content = str_replace(';}', '', $content);
  foreach(explode(';', $content) as $line) {
    $part = explode(':', $line);
    $result[$header][$part[0]]=$part[1];    
  }
}'

Comment: [parser and lexer generators for PHP](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/parser-and-lexer-generators-for-php/) or you could rewrite this js css lexer: http://www.phpied.com/css-lexer/

Comment: please note that I fixed a bug in the accepted answer (half a year later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works in most, but not all cases:

```
$clean_css_str = preg_replace('#/\*.*\*/#U', ' ', str_replace("\n", ' ', $css_str));
$r = preg_match_all('/([^{]+){([^}]*)}/', $clean_css_str, $match_arr);
$sel_arr = array_map('trim', $match_arr[1]);
$css_arr = array_map('trim', $match_arr[2]);
$css_map = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $r; $i++) {
   if (preg_match_all('/([-a-z_][-a-z0-9_]*)\s*:\s*([^;]+)(;|$)/i', $css_arr[$i], $match_arr)) {
      $prop_arr = array_map('trim', $match_arr[1]);
      $decl_arr = array_map('trim', $match_arr[2]);
      $decl_map = array_combine($prop_arr, $decl_arr);
      foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $sel_arr[$i])) as $sel) {
         $css_map[$sel] = isset($css_map[$sel]) ? array_merge($css_map[$sel], $decl_map) : $decl_map;
      }
   }
}
var_export($css_map); echo "\n";
```

It does not work with @ rules, opening braces in selectors, closing braces or semicolons in declarations, and a few more exotic cases.

(please note: I fixed a bug in the above code half a year after it was accepted)

Comment: That works like a treat. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have found a little problem, i get the following error 'Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have at least 1 element'. This is when e.g. i try to pass background: none; into the function. I do not think that it will allow the value none. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Fixed for empty blocks. But I don't think that the value "none" was the problem, maybe you had an invalid syntax that prevented the match of any content in some block (which would make it appear as empty).

Comment: an example of invalid syntax could be a `;` instead of a `:` - let me know

Comment: it seems to be working now. thanks for the help. not sure what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [CSS parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser), there are tons of them on github.